# django commit_on_success usage

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a sequence of methods to use in another method call i.e handle of a management/command in django. How do I ensure completion of all the methods in the sequence. All these methods do not necessarily return a value. Can I use commit_on_success for the handle? Is there any other better method. Basically some of the methods update some important values in the postgresql tables on the basis of which certain decisions are taken for the next method call. Please revert.I am using django 1.6.5 on linux

Comment: Note that `commit_on_success` is deprecated in Django 1.6. You should use the new transaction features (e.g. [`atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic)).

Answer (score 0):

I had the simmilar issue and I was using `transaction.commit_manually`.
The code I have looks like this:

```
# Some actions before
with transaction.commit_manually():
    try:
        # Some actions that will be saved in DB
    except:
        # Log error message
        transaction.rollback() # Rollback if there was an error during the execution
        return error_response # Stop execution of the method and return the response
    transaction.commit() # If return was not initiated before, it means that there were no errors, so we can do commit
```

Comment: Thanks for the response http://stackoverflow.com/users/1291512/whiteangel, I have read this, also note that the command is a cron job which executes every 10 minutes. So how does this kind of manual commit come into picture?

Comment: Hi, @user956424, there should be no problems at all with the cron job. If you are starting it as a django management command using manage.py - you should have all related settings loaded and transaction should be executed absolutely well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1291512/whiteangel, let me try and get back, thx a lot